# Prove that if A and B are sets such that $A \cup B \neq \emptyset$, then $A \neq \emptyset$ or $B \neq \emptyset$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that if A and B are sets such that $A \cup B \neq \emptyset$, then $A \neq \emptyset$ or $B \neq \emptyset$.

It was suggested to me that the easiest way to approach this was with a proof by elimination. I wasn't sure how to start the elimination approach so I instead tried to use another way by "Supposing that $A \cup B \neq \emptyset$ and that $A = \emptyset$" but I do not think this was a proper approach.

Comment: A short direct proof: If $A \cup B \neq \emptyset $, then there is $x$ such that $x\in A\cup B$. So $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, and so $A\neq \emptyset$ or $B\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: A short proof using elimination: Suppose $A \cup B \neq \emptyset $. Then there is $x$ such that $x\in A\cup B$. If $A=\emptyset$  then $x\in B$, so  $B\neq \emptyset$.  Thus, we have $A\neq \emptyset$ or $B\neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest here is to prove the contrapositive: if $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\emptyset$, then clearly $A\cup B=\emptyset$ and we're done.

Comment: That makes more sense because I think using elimination would be more work than necessary.

Comment: Matt you can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

One can also proceed directly. Suppose $A\cup B\ne\emptyset,$ meaning that there is some $x\in A\cup B.$ Since $$A\cup B=\{y:y\in A\text{ or }y\in B\}$$ by (naive) definition, then $x\in A$ or $x\in B,$ so $A\ne\emptyset$ or $B\ne\emptyset.$